# How do ligands and coordination complexes work in this case with copper (II) chloride?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, bond, aqueous-solution

What happens when Ammonia  is added to an (aq) solution of copper II chloride?

$\ce{CuCl2 + NH3 ->\; ?}$

I know that ligands bond with metals to form ion but I'm not sure about how they work in a reaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When solid $\ce{CuCl2}$ is dissolved in water, *aquo* complexes are formed.

$\ce{CuCl2_{(s)} + H2O -> [Cu(H2O)6]^2+ + 2 Cl-}$

Addition of ammonia results in a ligand exchange reaction to give *tetrammine* complexes.

$\ce{[Cu(H2O)6]^2+ + 4 NH3 -> [Cu(NH3)4(H2O)2]^2+ + 2 H2O}$

Comment: I get how NH3 as a ligand replaces (H2O)6 but how did you come uo with the products? [Cu(NH3)4(H2O)2]^2+ + 2H2O Thanks.